# iOS TableView of Facebook Friends Empty

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview

I am trying to display my friends from *Facebook* in my app in a `UITableView`.  However, my `TableView` is staying empty.  Here is my code for pulling up the `UITableView`.

```
-(IBAction)testfriends {
    FBFriendPickerViewController *friendPickerController = [[FBFriendPickerViewController alloc] init];
    friendPickerController.title = @"Pick Friends";
    [friendPickerController loadData];

    // Use the modal wrapper method to display the picker.
    [friendPickerController presentModallyFromViewController:self animated:YES handler:
     ^(FBViewController *innerSender, BOOL donePressed) {
         if (!donePressed) {
             return;
         }

         NSString *message;

         if (friendPickerController.selection.count == 0) {
             message = @"<No Friends Selected>";
         } else {

             NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

             // we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
             // at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class
             for (id<FBGraphUser> user in friendPickerController.selection) {
                 if ([text length]) {
                     [text appendString:@", "];
                 }
                 [text appendString:user.name];
             }
             message = text;
         }

         [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Picked:"
                                     message:message
                                    delegate:nil
                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                           otherButtonTitles:nil]
          show];
     }];
}
```

What am I missing here?  It is taken straight from the Facebook Sample, but even in the sample app, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 4/30/2014, with the launch of the Graph API v2.0, you'll need to request the user_friends permission and you will only receive friends who also use the app.

Comment: Ok, but I could use taggable_friends, populate a tableview, and then post something that tags the friends I select (after this new review process for Facebook)?  I have the code now setup to return me the NSDictionary of all taggable friends, and I get the valueForKey name from that and build a tableview with those names, but how would I set it up to tag multiple friends, and then use the Graph to POST to wall tagging those?

Comment: That's a separate and very different question.